# Android: Change Device language automatically without device restart

Tags: android, shell, adb

I can change device language using following adb command:

```
adb shell setprop persist.sys.language fr;setprop persist.sys.country CA;stop;sleep 5;start
```

This command will restart device after changing device language. But is it possible to change devices language without restart device?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in a testing context, you could use the fastlane [screengrab](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/screengrab) tool for changing the locale of your device directly.

I myself was looking for a possibility to change the locale of the device from ADB, but failed finding one. In the end I implemented a similar approach tp screengrab. There seems to be no easy way of changing the locale on the phone. Only triggering a configuration change directly through a `BroadcastReceiver` makes it work. It's called [DevSet](https://github.com/tynn/DevSet) and after setting everything up a more or less simple call to ADB will change the locale (on all devices I've tested so far):

```
adb shell am broadcast -n dev.set/.locale --es l {locale}
```